# How to call computed props dynamically on templates?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have something like that:

```js
<script>
export default {
    computed: {
        something () {
            return 'foo' 
        }
    }
}
</script>

<template>
   <div>
      <!-- But of course it doesnt work because we cant call "this" on templates -->
       <span v-if="this['something'] === 'foo'"> Computed property called dynamically </span>
   </div>
</template>
```

So there is some way to call computed props dynamically?

Comment: You *can* use `this` in templates, especially for dynamic props.

Comment: [Demo of your exact code](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/jOmjLdN)

Comment: I assume your actual app has a variable instead of `'something'`, as in `this[myVariable]`. That also works.

Comment: @tony19 so `this` only works when we use to call dynamic props?

Comment: No, `this` always works in the template. However, my opinion is it should only be used for dynamic props (e.g., `this[myVariable]`). When the prop is static (`this['something']`) then just use the prop name without `this`: `v-if="something === 'foo'"`.

Comment: @tony19 I have no idea what is happening, but my code says cant call prop of undefined, in this case "this" is undefined when i call on template. I call it inside a for, on a if statement

Comment: I made a method called `computed (prop) { return this[prop] }` because `this` simply doesnt work on templates for me, idk, i'm using Vue 2, maybe you talking about Vue 3?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236187/discussion-between-joao-hamerski-and-tony19).

Answer (score 0):

Inside `template`, `this` is completely option. You can use `computed` properties and other state variables/methods using one of the following ways:

```
<template>
   <div>
       <span v-if="something === 'foo'"> Computed property called dynamically </span>
   </div>
</template>

or

<template>
   <div>
       <span v-if="this.something === 'foo'"> Computed property called dynamically </span>
   </div>
</template>
```